# What does the Sample Project types stand for when creating a Gradle project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gradle

When creating a new Gradle Project in Eclipse there's a list of Sample Projects to choose from.

What's the difference between each one?

[image: Gradle]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come across with the answer.

The following samples are currently available:

> - **Java Quickstart:** A 'single project' sample project from the official Gradle distribution. It is described [here](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html).
> - **Java API and Implementation:** Another 'single project' sample from the official Gradle distribution. Shows you how to customize your project's layout.
> - **Flat Java Multi Project:** A sample we created to demonstrates the most common
>     'multi-project' layout that works well within Eclipse. There is a single root project that has most of the build logic, and a number of sub-projects containing the actual source code of the project. Many SpringSource projects have Gradle builds and use this layout (e.g. spring-integration, spring-framework, spring-security).
>     Note:

** Note: 'multi-project' samples will result in the creation of several projects in your workspace. Only the root project will get the name you typed into the Wizard. There is currently no mechanism to select names for subprojects. These project's names are simply 'hard-coded' into the sample project(s).